# Remove and Insert UI element in a Single ObserveEvent in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I am building a dashboard with 3 selectizeinput boxes. When a user selects an option in a single selectizinput box, the options in the remaining unselected filters will get updated. It may take a few seconds for the updating to occur. For a given selectizeinput box, you can choose up to 3 options. The selection of option is handled in an observeEvent. In the real app, there are multiple observeEvents to handle the selection of options in multiple selectizeinput boxes.

I want a small action button saying "Done" to appear below the selectizeinput boxes only after the updating occurs. This works for the first option that is selected. When the user selects a second option from the same selectizeinput box, I want the "Done" button to disappear and re-appear only when the other selectizeinput boxes get updated. I have tried using removeUI and insertUI for this purpose but it isn't working.

I have already tried shinyjs library's hide(), show() and toggle() to hide the "Done" action button during the updating and only show it after the updating is done. But it didn't work.

ui.R

```
sidebar <- shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(
              id = "sidebarmenu",
              menuItem(h4("Sample"), tabName = "map"),
              conditionalPanel("input.sidebarmenu === 'map'",
                               selectizeInput(
                                 "srcLoc", label="Filter 1", choices=srcC, selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE, options=list(maxItems=nSrc, placeholder="")
                               )
                               ,
                               selectizeInput(
                                 "srcCity", label="Filter 2", choices=NULL, selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE, options=list(maxItems=nCity, placeholder="")
                               ),
                               selectizeInput(
                                 "destLoc", label="Filter 3", choices=destT, selected=NULL, multiple=TRUE, options=list(maxItems=nDest, placeholder="")
                               ),
                               tags$div(id="placeholder")

              )
  )
  )

body <- shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="map"
    )
  )
)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Trial"),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer<- function(input,output,session) {

  observeEvent(input$srcLoc, {
    removeUI("#done")
    if (!is.null(input$srcLoc) & is.null(input$srcCity) & is.null(input$destLoc)) {
      df <- getDf(locsAgg, srcc, destt, srcregg, destregg, regionCountryCity, input$srcLoc, input$srcCity, input$destLoc)

      if (length(input$srcLoc)>1) {
        locc <- paste(input$srcLoc, collapse=" -> ")
      } else {
        locc <- input$srcLoc
      }

      cities <- getCity4(df, locc, srcregg, srcc, regionCountryCity)
      sc <- sort(cities[!cities %in% c(NA,"NA")])
      if (length(sc) > 1) {
        sc <- as.data.table(sort(cities[!cities %in% c(NA,"NA")]))
      } 

      destChoice <- unique(getLocs2(df,"S"))
      destChoice <- destChoice[!destChoice %in% c(NA,"NA")]
      if (length(destChoice)>1) {
        destChoice <- as.data.table(destChoice)
      }

      updateSelectizeInput(session, "destLoc", 
                           choices=destChoice,
                           selected=input$destLoc,
                           options=list(placeholder="Select a Country",maxItems=nDest))
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "srcCity",
                           choices=sc,
                           selected=input$srcCity,
                           options=list(placeholder="Select a City",maxItems=nCity))
      insertUI("#placeholder",where="afterEnd",ui = 
    }
  })

}
```

Is there a way to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please provide `srcC`, `destT`, etc.